# Возможно ли получение сложного объекта из БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Привет!

Опыта в EntityFramework нет, найти ответ в сети не удалось, везде описан подход CodeFirst, а я использую подход DBFirst.

В БД есть объект Mark и некоторые поля являются ключами других таблиц-справочников. Создаю EDMX модель, отмечаю все таблицы мне необходимые, вижу их на диаграмме, студия создаёт классы под объекты из таблиц. Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы в созданном объекте Mark в свойствах были сами значения из справочников, а не номера их ключей.

Возможно ли такое? Если нет - каким образом мне тогда создавать объект с необходимыми мне свойствами?

Comment: в классах которых создает студия есть навигационные свойства, берите значения от туда.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: в БД есть таблицы (отношения) и строки (записи) в них, объектов в БД не бывает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создавать на стороне сервера БД представление, которое объединяет вашу таблицу и таблицы-справочники при помощи `inner join`. Далее обновите модель в VS, EF сразу же создаст дополнительный класс, который будет описывать структуру Вашего созданного представления. Далее его можно использовать в коде.

Есть второй подход - составление вашего представления на стороне клиента путем использования навигационных свойств либо объединения ваших таблиц используя LINQ.

Выбирайте, какой подход вам больше подходит.

Comment: А подробнее про второй подход где можно узнать? Я нашел навигационные свойства, но как именно ими пользоваться не понял.

Comment: @Nova здесь на примерах хорошо поясняется использование навигационных свойств. https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php

Comment: @Nova здесь показывают синтаксис подхода через LINQ  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql